# need to call soap ws without wsdl

Tags: java, web-services

I am new bie to web service.
This web service is provided siebel guys.
I need to call one web service.
My client provided me following details.

Here is the SOAP. For prod use this as you endpoint:

http://myhost:myport/eai_anon_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=SecureWebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&WSSOAP=1

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:user="http://avusa.com/exclusive/UserRegistration">
<soapenv:Header>  
     <UsernameToken xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">username</UsernameToken>  
     <PasswordText xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">password</PasswordText>  
     <SessionType xmlns="http://siebel.com/webservices">None</SessionType>  
</soapenv:Header>  
<soapenv:Body>  
     <user:Check_spcLogin_Input>  
     <user:Process_spcInstance_spcId>?</user:Process_spcInstance_spcId>  
     <user:UserLogin>username</user:UserLogin>   
     <user:Object_spcId></user:Object_spcId>  
     <user:Siebel_spcOperation_spcObject_spcId></user:Siebel_spcOperation_spcObject_spcId>  
     <user:Error_spcCode></user:Error_spcCode>  
     <user:Error_spcMessage></user:Error_spcMessage>  
     </user:Check_spcLogin_Input>  
</soapenv:Body>
```

My application is developed using spring and struts.
I need to call this web service.
Can anybody give me suggestion or url which helps me.
I googled for so much i havent find any proper information. May be i am not understanding properly. But with the information above can we call a web service.

Thanks
RS

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using spring in your application, then it makes sense to use Spring WebServices to access to the service.

The manual has a [chapter on how to use Spring-WS from the client](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html). The good news here is that Spring-WS has no requirement on the target service WSDL, in fact it actively discourages it. You can invoke the webservice using a variety of bindings, such as JAXB or raw DOM if you choose. The docs cover all the options.

Comment: I think this is the best option available, unless constraint by something which we do not know about.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt. I will work on that, Once again thanks

Answer (score 1):

Webservices in siebel are defined in SOAP form, siebel guys have sent you a SOAP message, ask to siebel guys for the wsdl file. They can get it from siebel client application inbound web services. Then you can use the spring  framework suggested by skaffman, [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/). These frameworks provide you an abstraction in the form of classes to call the web services.